# Will releasing an NSMutableArray having allocated UIViews release the UIViews as well?

Tags: iphone, memory-management, uiview, nsmutablearray

Ok so here's what I'm doing.

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

UIView *tempview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];
[array addObject:tempView];

UIView *tempview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];
[array addObject:tempView2];

[array release];
```

Will the releasing of the array, release the two allocated UIViews as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `copy`, `alloc`, `retain`, or `new` something, *you are responsible for sending it either `release` or `autorelease`*.

*You* said `[[UIView alloc] init...]` so *you* must `release` the resulting object.

Answer (score 2):

You are responsible for releasing the views since you created them. Here is how it goes:

You create the views with a retain count of 1.
When they are added to the array, it will retain them (retain count = 2).
When you release the array, it will release the views (retain count = 1).
You still need to release them.

The correct code would be:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  

UIView *tempview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];
[array addObject:tempView];
[tempview release];

UIView *tempview2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 30, 320, 460)];
[array addObject:tempView2];
[tempview2 release];

[array release];
```

Comment: As a side note, the views would in this case indeed be released with the final release of the array.